# How to parse this decenturl code?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have this code:

```
["ok", "Google", "google"]
```

That I get from `decenturl.com/api-title?u=google.com`. This API gets the title of a site, but it is "encoded" in the format above. What is the format of this? I tried to search for it, but without the name I can't do anything. It looks like JSON, but it isn't, I guess.

Anyway, how do I parse this in C#? Will be better if this work in framework 2.0, but if can't, I accept above frameworks. There is a built-in method for that? Or I need to do it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're trapped in a framework version that is 10 years old? I'd strongly advise you to try to update to a more modern version of .NET if at all possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, some users still use old versions of Windows, so is needed to make it run even in oldest systems. Can't do anything about it.

Comment: Just how far back do you need to support? How long are you willing to support your users after Microsoft has stopped supporting those versions of Windows? (Windows XP supports .NET 3.5 - are you going back earlier than that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* JSON, just for an array. Assuming the URL *always* gives you back JSON, you could parse it like this (using [Json.NET](http://json.net), which still supports .NET 2.0):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "[\"ok\", \"Google\", \"google\"]";
        var array = JArray.Parse(json);
        Console.WriteLine(array[0]); // For example
    }
}
```